# Good Design in Generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a design question. Below is TimeStamp Interface

```
/**
 * <T> Type of Timestamp. For ex: Date, long, Calendar etc
 * 
 */
public interface TimeStamp<T> extends Comparable<TimeStamp<T>>
{

  /**
   * Returns the timestamp. 
   * @return 
   */
  public T getTimeStamp();

}
```

I basically want to have a `List` class that can only contain TimeStamps. Adding anything on the list will basically depend upon the timestamp. How should be my List class declaration.

If I decide for composition, the code will look like:

```
public class TimeList<T> implements List<TimeStamp<T>> 
{    
  private List<TimeStamp<?>> list = new ArrayList<TimeStamp<?>>();
  //other list methods who will return based on list above
  .....
}
```

But the above does not make sense. For example if I have a class `DefaultTimeStamp implments TimeStamp<Long>` and instantiate TimeList as

```
TimeList<DefaultTimeStamp> l = new TimeList<DefaultTimeStamp>();
```

Then anycall to `l.add(elem)` will expect a `TimeStamp<DefaultTimeStamp>` which is wrong.

A declaration of: `public class TimeList<TimeStamp<T>> implements List<TimeStamp<T>>` would give compile time error

What should be the declaration of my `TimeList<Type>`? Ultimately it is just a list containing only TimeStamps

Comment: Because adding anything to list will depend on its timestamp.

Comment: do you want TimeList to contain TimeStamp<T> for particular T of for any T?

Comment: Yes. That is needed for calculations

Comment: Maybe you are better of to make TimeStamp non generic and use covariant return types.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you want to do

```
TimeList<DefaultTimeStamp> l = new TimeList<DefaultTimeStamp>();
```

If you want to be able to add any kind of `TimeStamp<Long>`. The above way would force users to use `DefaultTimeStamp` if you had some implementation specific reason to do so... but usually not, obivously.

```
TimeList<TimeStamp<Long>> l = new TimeList<TimeStamp<Long>>();
DefaultTimeStamp dts = new DefaultTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
l.add(dts);
```

Should work just fine!

Comment: That is exactly I did not want. i mean- TimeList<DefaultTimeStamp> l = new TimeList<DefaultTimeStamp>();

Comment: I know you don't want to do that, do the bottom thing :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make the TimeList class generic. You simple could declare the TimeList as:

```
public class TimeList implements List<Timestamp> {

private List<Timestamp> list = new ArrayList<Timestamp>();
```

and then use it

```
    TimeList l = new TimeList();

    l.add(new DefaultTimestamp1());
    l.add(new DefaultTimestamp2());
```

It works perfectly. You can only add objects that extend the `Timestamp` interface.

Comment: This is the other solution. +1

Comment: But this would give several compile time warnings.

Comment: I had no warnings, can you show the warnings you get and say which jdk are you using?

Comment: This should give warning in JDK 1.6+ because Timestamp is a raw type and should be parametrized. `List<Timestamp>` is essentially the same as `List<Timestamp<?>>`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TimeList<T> extends ArrayList<TimeStamp<T>>{
}
```

That's it.

Comment: If his list methods are only returning based on his `private` variable, then this is a good way indeed. However, by implementing the `List` interface he's hiding methods that exists in `ArrayList` and not in the `List` interface. (Such as `ensureCapacity`).

Answer (score 0):

Though similar can be repeated in Java, in scala one can do it by:

```
trait TimeStamp[T <: Comparable[T]] extends Comparable[TimeStamp[T]]
{
def getTimeStamp:T;
def compareTo(to:TimeStamp[T]) =this.getTimeStamp.compareTo(to.getTimeStamp) 
}
```

And TimeList declaration is as follows:

```
class TimeList[T <: TimeStamp[_]] extends ArrayList[T]
```

Comment: Who said anything about Scala?